# Preg Replace a curly apostrophe?

Tags: php

I'm trying to use preg replace to replace a single curly postrophe (amongst other characters but I have excluded them from my example).

```
preg_replace('/[‘]/', 'x', '‘');
```

Unfortunately the above outputs `xxx`, I would expect to only see a single `x`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Just one curly, the above code produces three xxx, should only be one.

Comment: It's a multibyte character. Need utf8 modifier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it unicode capable by adding the `u` flag.

```
echo preg_replace("/[‘]/u", 'x', '‘');
```

prints

```
x
```